# Using GetCpInfo

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to write a small program to run `GetCpInfo`, but am getting an identifier not found error .  I am including `windows.h` and using visual studio.  IntelliSense is autocomplete for me when I type in GetCp.  Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;




int main()
{
    LPCPINFO cpinfo;
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    bool test = GetCpInfo(37, cpinfo);
    int x;
    cin>>x;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The function is named `GetCPInfo`. Remember that the language is case sensitive.
2. You are passing an uninitialized pointer.

You need the following:

```
CPINFO cpinfo;
bool succeeded = GetCPInfo(37, &cpinfo);
```